# A diifficulty in understanding a sentence in a paragraph in Guillemin and Pollack p.77

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, compactness

The paragraph is given below:

[image]

But I have a difficulty in understanding the sentence starting in the forth line by  "If we furthur ...." until its end, could anyone explain it for me please?

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is all basic point-set stuff.  $X \cap Z$ is a $0$-dimensional manifold, so it is discrete.  If both $X$ and $Z$ are closed then so is $X \cap Z$.  If, say, $X$ is compact, then $X \cap Z \subseteq X$.  Hence $X \cap Z$ is a closed subset of a compact space, so it is compact.  Since it is compact and discrete, it is finite.

Answer (score 3):

If $X$ and $Z$ are closed and at least one of them is compact, then $X\cap Z$ is closed and compact (the intersection of closed sets is closed, and a closed subset of a compact set is compact).  Then, the statement is that compact zero-dimensional submanifolds must be finite, which is clear.  Zero-dimensional manifolds are discrete, and discrete compact sets are finite.